# Некоректное выделение элементов списка recyclerView согласно наличию id элемента в бд

Tags: android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

У меня есть список в котором отображаются вакансии. Я хочу сделать выделение элемента при наличии в бд его id. Все вроде как нормально, пока я не начну прокручивать список и начинаю замечать что у меня выделяются не только те что нужные элементы но и дальше в той же последовательности. Вот как я выделяю элемент:

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final JobHolder jobHolder, int position) {
....
db = new DataBaseHelper(ctx);
if (db.CheckIsDataAlreadyInDBorNot(String.valueOf(jobModel.getId()))) {
jobHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(ctx.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
}
....
}
```

вот к примеру у меня должны быть выделены 1,2 и 5 элементы списка, в итоге я получаю 1,2,5 12,13,17,23,24,28 то есть через каждые 11 элементов все повторяется. Вероятнее всего это связанно с тем что список постоянно обновляется, хотя на экране у меня помещается 8 элементов. Не могу решить эту проблему. Пробовал все закинуть в цикл в котором проверять наличие в бд id но не помогло.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте в условие:

```
else {
    jobHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(COLOR.Transparent); //или любой другой нулевой бэк
}
```

Дело в том, что ваш вьюхолдер используется несколько раз. И при повторном использовании не перекрашивается назад.

Comment: я почему-то и не подумал за такое решение, спасибо большое за помощь :)